# magento Newsletter css placing at homepage

Tags: css, magento, html, newsletter

I have do research and cannot find the resolution on how to make the newsletter's block displayed as center position. I understand there have HTML code scripts and also its css.

I got some answer but well that not working, hope community give some help on this.

Please check the image where the newsletter block is at left(newsletter-block-not-center).

[image]

HTML codes im used:

```
<div style="background-color: #fff;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Subscribe now and save more than everything!</h2>

                <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: #999; line-height: 23px;">Grab a fantastic saving when you subscribe now. It's not just a saving, great tips, free gitft and other secrets are awaiting you.</p>
                <div class="newsletter-container">{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is css update im attached on the existing css under path: /skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css and css file name is styles.css

Css updated (adding into it):

`.class{ display:inline-block; text-align:center; float:center; }`

and there have existing newsletter css which is available in this link:
http://myarttees.com/v1/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/styles.css

help me on how to make the newsletter centered. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to give display:block by fixed width and then center it.

```
.newsletter-container {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]